# bot counting command discord

Tags: python, count, counter, bots, discord

I have a private bot on discord, i've been trying to make him count a command and adding '+1' everytime I write that one command but it stays at 1 and can't go further : [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzAtD.png)

I think what I want to do is to make it save the number of time the command has been writen and add +1 to this number ; Should I do a loop or something ?

Basically what I want is something like this in python for a discord bot : https://docs.nightbot.tv/commands/variables/count

Comment: you set `counter=0` every time the method is called.

Comment: Is there another way that I can put everything in "cmd_thatcommand" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resetting your counter variable back to zero every time you call the function with the line

```
counter = 0
```

You can solve this by declaring the counter variable outside of the function and by removing the

```
counter = 0
```

line in the function afterwards.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I've been trying to put counter = 0 before but it keeps doing :
**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment**
I tried with `global counter` before the `counter += 1` and the same thing happen

Comment: @Shakam Can you post your code? Should work with `global counter`

Comment: Nevermind, it worked at the second try, I don't know why..
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting your counter on every call, declaring your counter outside your function will solve the problem

```
counter = 0

async def cmg_thatcommand(self,channel):
 ...
 counter+=1
 ...
 return Response('you wrote that command {} time.' .format(counter))
```