# Trying to count up with discord bot

Tags: discord

I'm very new to this. I dabbled in javascript about 10-15 years ago, but it was just editing existing files. I've been searching but I can't find a definitive guide for how to do this. I'm trying to make a command, and have the bot count up with it. Here's almost all of my code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === `!test`) {
        async def cmd_thatcommand(self,channel):
        await self.safe_send_message(channel, "+1")
        counter += 1
        return Response('command used {} times'.format(counter))
    } else if (message.content === `!beep`) {
        message.channel.send('Boop.');
    } else if (message.content === `!server`) {
        message.channel.send(`Server name: ${message.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
    } else if (message.content === `!user-info`) {
        message.channel.send(`Your username: ${message.author.username}\nYour ID: ${message.author.id}`);
    }
});
```

I've attempted a few lines I found online (such as [bot counting command discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675454/bot-counting-command-discord) )but they always throw some kind of error. The one it gives for the above code is:

```
                async def cmd_thatcommand(self,channel):
                      ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)[39m
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m
```

The guide I found for this uses Node and ESLint (if that helps at all).

Comment: Please add the exact error message that you are facing and maybe include a link to the guide you're following

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The first bit I tried was from this thread, but I don't think there's enough code for it to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675454/bot-counting-command-discord

Comment: Sorry for the spam. edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

def is not a thing in Java Script. Try using function instead if def. also instead if using ":" you have to use "{}" for example.

```
function example(){
     console.log("This is how you make a function in Java Script");
```

}
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function